# syntax error at or near "{" in CREATE TABLE command

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a new table for my database, and I'm trying to follow the Postgresql syntax very closely (according to my class materials) so the table will be created, but it doesn't want to work. what am I doing wrong?

```
    CREATE TABLE rosters {
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_ids) REFERENCES users (id),
    phonenumbers INTEGER,
    };
```

I'm sure it's something minor - but I've been stuck. Thanks. The error I'm getting is

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
    LINE 1: CREATE TABLE rosters {
                                 ^
    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
    SQL state: 42601
    Character: 22
```

Comment: Take a look at [documentation for CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html), perhaps? See if you can spot the difference between their examples and your code.

Comment: please really read the documentation. as well note difference between ( and {

Comment: Also, I don't know the contents of your course materials. It is possible that the materials _did_ recommend the syntax with curly braces. But postgresql couldn't care less about that. When in doubt, consult the official documentation. This is true for everything, not only postgresql.

Comment: Find a different class or school if that is what they are teaching as valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `(` `)`, not `{` `}`.

```
CREATE TABLE rosters (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_ids) REFERENCES users (id),
    phonenumbers INTEGER
);
```

Comment: I am not sure about the `foreign key` keywords. I believe it should be `event_id integer references events(id)`

Comment: @gusto2 According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html it's valid syntax for a table constraint, but I'm not sure if the `event_id` column has to be defined separately for this to work.

Comment: I believe so (event_id column needs to be declared separately before) so your example may be not working. But let Kim figure it out..

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the last comma `phonenumbers INTEGER`

and replace `{` and `}` with `(` and `)`